# Multiple touch listener like "Enable developer options and debugging" feature of Google

Tags: android

I have a SettingsFragment like this:

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
```

and I am getting a button like this:

```
Preference button_about = findPreference("button_about");
button_about.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new 
Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) {
            // do something
            return true;
        }
    });
```

I would like to detect if the user tabs the button_about multiple times consecutively in a fast way. This feature is also used by Google to switch a phone to developer mode by [tabbing the "Build number" button 7 times consecutively](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options.html). I want to implement the same feature in my app. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a counter to keep track of how many taps, and a `Handler` to reset the counter in case a set amount of time has passed.

Example:

```
private static final int MAX_DELAY = 2000;
private static final int MIN_TAPS = 5;
private int mCounter = 0;
private Handler mHandler;

private void setOnClickListener() {
    Preference button_about = findPreference("button_about");
    button_about.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) {

            mCounter++;

            //if the user did not tap the button within MAX_DELAY, the counter resets
            if (mHandler == null) {
                mHandler = new Handler();
                mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mCounter = 0;
                    }
                }, MAX_DELAY);
            }

            if (mCounter >= MIN_TAPS) {
                // user tapped MIN_TAPS times consecutively
                // do something...
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the code is almost correct. The postDelayed call must not be within the if (mHandler == null) condition because otherwise it won't register the event. The rest is perfect. Thanks!